# NodeJS quiz scoring issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have made a quiz website using the "MEN stack" (no React), if you can call it that. The link to the repo is [here](https://github.com/arkaseth/quiz_website).

While testing the app locally, the quiz works as intended. No issues. The scoring is done once the user submits the form. I have a few keywords for each question, and upon submission, I check if the user has entered any of the keywords I had set. The code for that can be seen below.

```
router.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  let sub = Object.values(req.body);
  let ans = [];
  sub.forEach((opt, idx) => {
    opt = opt.toLowerCase();
    ans[idx] = opt.split(" ");
  });
  let score = 0;
  ans.forEach(async (opt, idx) => {
    const corr = await Question.findOne({
      index: idx,
    });
    corr.answer = corr.answer.toLowerCase();
    let correct = corr.answer.split(" ");
    let res = correct.some((val) => {
      return opt.indexOf(val) >= 0;
    });
    if (res) {
      score += 10;
    }
  });
  setTimeout(async () => {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {
      score,
      completed: true,
      submittedAt: Date.now(),
      answers: sub,
    });
  }, 1000);

  // console.log(req.user.id);
  res.render("finished");
});
```

As you can see, I had to use a `setTimeout` to calculate the score, as it wasn't working without it. I guessed the asynchronous nature of the calculating function caused it. If you can suggest a better alternative, it'll be great. An example of one question and its keywords are given below:

```js
{
    description: "A company was started by the Maharaja of Mysore, Nalvadi Krishnaraja W..."
    answer: "vote voting voter voters indelible ink"
    index: 3
    __v: 0
}
```

Once the quiz went live, we had around 150 participants for the quiz. Upon submission, there was one issue; not all of the users' scores was being calculated correctly. Some were due to different answers from the keywords, but I couldn't find any reason for the other ones.

One such unexplainable instance was as follows. The first pic is of a submission in the actual quiz, the second one is a test I did just now, using the same answers as of that participant:

Actual submission:

```js
{
    score: 0
    completed: true
    answers: [
      "Trump Towers", "Shakuntala Devi", "Sir", "Voter ink", "",
      "Indian Constitution", "Saera jahe se accha", "Sunfeast open",
      "Dunlop", "Robert Clive", "APJ Abdul Kalam", 
      "Signing the ordinance in Indian emergency",
      "Indian nuclear operation in pokhran", "Mohammad Salim",
      "Swami Vivekananda", "Bubble wrap", "", "Inquilab",
      "Chintaman ganesh temple", "Jamtara"
    ]
}
```

My test:

```js
{
    score: 140
    completed: true
    answers: [
      "Trump Towers", "Shakuntala Devi", "Sir", "Voter ink", "",
      "Indian Constitution", "Saera jahe se accha", "Sunfeast open",
      "Dunlop", "Robert Clive", "APJ Abdul Kalam", 
      "Signing the ordinance in Indian emergency",
      "Indian nuclear operation in pokhran", "Mohammad Salim",
      "Swami Vivekananda", "Bubble wrap", "", "Inquilab",
      "Chintaman ganesh temple", "Jamtara"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the answers are exactly the same. Even the cases are the same. The correct score for the above submissions is 140, as I have obtained above.

I guess (a wild guess) the issue might be because of the `setTimeout`. Any alternative for that scoring method will be helpful.

I will be grateful for any help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please include actual code in the question, not images of it.

Comment: Hey @ScottSauyet. I added the actual code snippet in the question. Is it fine now?

Comment: Yes, that helps, but it would help to do the same for `example question`, `actual submission` and `my test`.

Comment: I was suggesting that you convert these to text.  Something like `{_id: ObjectId("5f3231922..."), description: "A company was started by...", answer: "vote voting ...", index: 3, __v: 0}`

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes... Sorry about that. I realised that and immediately deleted my comment. I have made the necessary changes. I've just omitted the ObjectId as it is not relevant in this case. Hope this is okay? Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: No problem.  When new to a community, it always takes some time to get used to its norms.  Thank you for making the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reconstructing too much of your code, I cannot be sure, but I suspect that you're right about the async problem.

There are other ways you might solve this (using `Promise.all` comes to mind), one possibility is to use an asynchronous version of `forEach` and then await the result of that before calling `User.findByIdAndUpdate`(now without a timeout.)  I haven't used it but a quick search for `async forEach` turned up [an article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) that looks promising.

This will probably require making the callback passed to `router.post` asynchronous as well.

If this doesn't do it, I would look at techniques of making a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The process often helps you find the answer on your own.  And when it doesn't, it gives something bite-sized for potential helpers to chew on.

Comment: Okay... Then I will look into it. I also did not know that an asynchronous version of `forEach` exists.